# True Polymorph & Simulacrum

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, simulacrum

If a player casts true polymorph on themselves and changes into an adult gold dragon and then casts Simulacrum, does it create a duplicate of a gold dragon or the player?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. Take the [tour] and check out the [help] as they are useful introductions to the site. I've closed this question as a duplicate of "[What do you get when making a Simulacrum of a True Polymorphed creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/146945/14878)" because I believe they are asking the same thing. This is not intended as a punishment of any kind. It's just how the site works and is intended to direct people to a "main" question about a particular topic.

Comment: If you believe they are *not* duplicates and the linked question doesn't answer yours then please [edit] your question to further explain what's confusing you and how the other question doesn't provide a satisfactory answer.